# Why Excel pivot table does not retrieve data for all dates?

Tags: ssas, pivot-table, olap-cube

Time table in SSAS Cube has all correct dates. And Data source view also has the correct data for those dates. However why Excel pivot table does not retrieve data from the specific week? (3rd week in the year)
Only 3rd week data is being missed in Excel pivot table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kv4J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could a filter in the pivot table be on by accident? Not in the data, but the table itself. Maybe a date got unticked? this could cause it.
[example of pivot filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK6rp.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably unlikely, but it could be that there's no data in that week for the measure you've selected.  Do you see the week if you browse the time dimension itself in SSDT?

Comment: Thank you SebTHU.
I found the root cause. That was the weekly job measuring all weekly units to date was failed due to unknown error so during calculating the 3rd week of the year, the job stopped so there happened the empty measures.